# convergence of integrals to 0

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\Omega \subset R^n$ be  a domain.

It is given that $\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{K}|f_n|=0  $ for every compact set $K \subset \Omega$

$|f_n|$ are bounded by some integrable function $g$ on $\Omega$

Can I say that $\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{\Omega}|f_n|=0  $ ?

Answer (score 1):

Since $\Omega$ is a domain in $\Bbb{R}^n$ (which I assume implies at least that $\Omega$ is open), we have $\Omega = \bigcup_n K_n$ for suitable compact subsets $K_n \subset \Omega$. By switching to $K_1 \cup \dots \cup K_n$ instead of $K_n$, we can also assume $K_n \subset K_{n+1}$.

Since $g$ is integrable on $\Omega$, we have (by dominated convergence) that

$$
\int_{\Omega \setminus K_n} |g| \, dx \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0.
$$

So for $\epsilon > 0$, we can choose some $N$ with $\int_{\Omega \setminus K_N} |g| \, dx < \epsilon$.

All in all, we get

$$
\int_\Omega |f_n| \, dx = \int_{K_N} |f_n| \, dx + \int_{\Omega \setminus K_n} |f_n| \, dx \leq \int_{K_N} |f_n| \, dx + \int_{\Omega \setminus K_N} |g| \, dx < \int_{K_N} |g| \, dx + \epsilon \to \epsilon,
$$
as $n\to \infty$.

Since $\epsilon > 0$ can be chosen arbitrarily, it is not hard to see that this implies $\int_\Omega |f_n| \, dx \to 0$.